# SAML OneLogin with SSO Circle : LogoutRequest returns StatusCode Requester instead of Success

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

Using the onelogin sample app as SP  with sso circle as IdP,  **login via SSOCircle IdP works**, but the **LogoutRequest**, after being validated, returns a LogOutResponse with **StatusCode** *Requester* instead of *Success* :

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse  xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-03-28T07:50:49Z" Destination="http://localhost:8080/onelogin-saml/sls.jsp" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_hexahexahexa">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<samlp:StatusCode xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
</samlp:StatusCode>
</samlp:Status>
</samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

IdP initiated Logout **works**.

I cannot figure out what am i missing in the properties configuration :

```
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.url=http://localhost:8080/onelogin-saml/sls.jsp
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
onelogin.saml2.sp.nameidformat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url=https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/publicidp
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.response.url=
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
```

Any input would be warmly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the **onelogin contributors**, i could solve the problem by storing the *nameId, sessionId and nameIdFormat* into the **session** at login, and then use them as parameters when calling the **logout** method. see closed issue for full code [here](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/154).